# How to nest multiple Promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I have multiple arrays of promises

Each array is put inside a `Promise.all()`

The `then()` of each `Promise.all()` adds data to a `tempObject`

I need to set the `tempObject` to state after `then()` of all `Promise.all()` are done executing.

What is the best approach (clean and readable code) to achieve this?

below is my code

```js
callSomeApis(parameter){
  let tempArray1 = [];
  let tempArray2 = [];
  this.props.dispatch(actions.callApi1(parameter)).then(callApi1Result =>{
    let callApi1ResultArray = callApi1Result.data.data;
    let PromiseArr1 = callApi1ResultArray.map((callApi1ResultArrayItem) => {
      return this.props.dispatch(actions.callApi2(callApi1ResultArrayItem.itemId));
    });
    let PromiseArr2 = callApi1ResultArray.map((callApi1ResultArrayItem) => {
      return this.props.dispatch(actions.callApi3(callApi1ResultArrayItem.itemId,parameter));
    });
    let PromiseArr3 = callApi1ResultArray.map((callApi1ResultArrayItem) => {
      return this.props.dispatch(actions.callApi4(callApi1ResultArrayItem.itemId));
    });
    Promise.all(PromiseArr1).then((callApi2Result) => {
      callApi2Result.map((callApi2ResultItem,index) => {
        callApi1ResultArray[index].api2Details = callApi2ResultItem.data.data[0];
        tempArray2.push({id: callApi2ResultItem.data.data[0].id, text: callApi2ResultItem.data.data[0].text});
      });
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return{
          stateKey1: {
            ...prevState.stateKey1,
            innerStateKey1: {
              ...prevState.stateKey1.innerStateKey1,
              list: tempArray2
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
    Promise.all(PromiseArr2).then((callApi3Result) => {
      callApi3Result.map((callApi3ResultItem, index) => {
        callApi1ResultArray[index].api3Result = callApi3ResultItem.data.data;
      });
    });
    Promise.all(PromiseArr3).then(callApi4Result => {
      callApi4Result.map((callApi4ResultItem,index) => {
        callApi1ResultArray[index].api4Result =  callApi4ResultItem.data.data;
      });
    });
    /**need to call this after the thens of  PromiseArr1, PromiseArr2 and PromiseArr3 are done executing*/
    this.setState({
      stateKey2:callApi1ResultArray
    })
    /** */
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able, you can also use `async`/`await`

```
async function (...) {
  const r1 = await Promise.all(...);
  // do something with r1
  const r2 = await Promise.all(...);
  // ...
}
```

and so on. Make sure you're using `Promise.all` on actions that can be parallelized (that also return a `Promise`), though.

I find that `async`/`await` really cleans up some nasty `Promise` chains/nesting and helps a lot with readability.

Answer (score 10):

`Promise.all` returns a promise so you can do:

```
const p1 = Promise.all(PromiseArr1).then(...);
const p2 = Promise.all(PromiseArr2).then(...);
const p3 = ...
Promise.all([p1, p2, ...]).then(...);
```

If all your promises are very similar you can clean it up by creating an array and mapping it to the promises.

Comment: Don't forget to check out my post down below. It fulfills many more of the questions requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.prototype.then` itself returns a promise. Therefore, you can legitimately and cleanly wrap the whole thing into a super `Promise.all` for both the best performance and code-size. also consider `"use strict";` and localizing globals and property lookups.

```
{ // avoid global leakage
    "use strict";
    let Promise = self.Promise;
    let Promise_all = Promise.all;
    let tempArray1 = [];
    let tempArray2 = [];
    callSomeApis(parameter){
        tempArray1.length = 0;
        tempArray2.length = 0;
        this.props.dispatch(actions.callApi1(parameter)).then(callApi1Result => {
            let callApi1ResultArray = callApi1Result.data.data;
            Promise_all([
                ////////////////// PromiseArr1 //////////////////
                Promise_all(
                    callApi1ResultArray.map((callApi1ResultArrayItem) => {
                        return this.props.dispatch(actions.callApi2(callApi1ResultArrayItem.itemId));
                    })
                ).then(
                    callApi2Result => {
                        callApi2Result.map((callApi2ResultItem,index) => {
                            callApi1ResultArray[index].api2Details = callApi2ResultItem.data.data[0];
                            tempArray2.push({id: callApi2ResultItem.data.data[0].id, text: callApi2ResultItem.data.data[0].text});
                        });
                        this.setState(prevState => ({
                            stateKey1: {
                                ...prevState.stateKey1,
                                innerStateKey1: {
                                    ...prevState.stateKey1.innerStateKey1,
                                    list: tempArray2
                                }
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                ),
                ////////////////// promiseArr2 //////////////////
                Promise_all(
                    callApi1ResultArray.map((callApi1ResultArrayItem) => {
                        return this.props.dispatch(actions.callApi3(callApi1ResultArrayItem.itemId,parameter));
                    })
                ).then(
                    callApi3Result => {
                        callApi3Result.map((callApi3ResultItem, index) => {
                            callApi1ResultArray[index].api3Result = callApi3ResultItem.data.data;
                        });
                    }
                ),
                ////////////////// PromiseArr3 //////////////////
                Promise_all(
                    callApi1ResultArray.map((callApi1ResultArrayItem) => {
                        return this.props.dispatch(actions.callApi4(callApi1ResultArrayItem.itemId));
                    })
                ).then(
                    callApi4Result => {
                        callApi4Result.map((callApi4ResultItem,index) => {
                            callApi1ResultArray[index].api4Result =  callApi4ResultItem.data.data;
                        });
                    }
                )
            ]).finally(
                /**need to call this after the thens of  PromiseArr1, PromiseArr2 and PromiseArr3 are done executing*/
                this.setState.bind(this, {
                    stateKey2: callApi1ResultArray
                })
                /** */
            );
        })
    }
}
```

Also, use `then` and `finally` responsibly for maximum performance. Use `then` when you require the return value and `finally` when you do not. Additionally, use block-statements in arrow functions appropriately for maximum code readability (arrow functions sometimes don't need them). Finally, sometimes try to reuse objects for better performance.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but `"use strict";` can be replaced by eslint with es6 modules, `let Promise_all = Promise.all` etc are pointless, and the deep nesting of your calls inside arguments is unpleasant. Coding styles are generally subjective though; some might prefer your way, so it's best left for the asker to decide.

Comment: @riwu Yes `Promise_all = Promise.all` is not required for the code to run, however it is required for the code to be "clean." Clean means performant and good coding practices. One of the best performance optimizations is to localize global variables to avoid expensive object property lookup and to allow the JIST compiler to better optimize your code. Also, the "deep nesting" is not actually deep nesting, rather it is just deep indentation. However, I am curious what you mean by "`"use strict";` can be replaced by eslint with es6 modules." I would like to know what you mean by this.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/strict "In ECMAScript modules, which always have strict mode semantics, the directives are unnecessary." As for your other comments, I guess we'd have to agree to disagree :)